# Angular - Dynamic text gradient

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass

I am attempting to dynamically change the gradient of some text in Angular (not the background but the text itself).

My current code is as follows:

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="name" [style.background]="gradient" 
    [style.-webkit-background-clip]="'text'"
    [style.background-clip]="'text'">Text Here</div>
```

**home.component.sass**

```
.name
    color: transparent
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif
    background: #FA8BFF
    background-clip: text
    -webkit-background-clip: text
```

**home.component.ts**

```
...
gradient : string = "linear-gradient(270deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)";

ngOnInit(): void {
  addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    var angle = event.clientX + event.clientY;
    this.gradient = `linear-gradient(${angle}deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)`;
  })
}
...
```

This works as expected when the page is loaded, but the instant that I trigger the mousemove event, the text turns into a square for the rest of the time the page is active.

How do I properly apply a dynamic gradient to my Angular text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

<strike>Use (see the "text" before linear-gradient)</strike>

```
gradient : string = "text linear-gradient(270deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)";

  addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    var angle = this.mouseAngle(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    this.gradient = `text linear-gradient(${angle}deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)`
  })
```

And

```
<div class="name" [style.background]="gradient">Text Here</div>
```

The before code only works in FireFox

**Work in FireFox, Chrome and Edge (I don't check others)**
We need change background-image, not background

```
.name{
    color: transparent;
    font-weight:800;
    font-size:16rem;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background: #FA8BFF;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text
  }

<div class="name" [style.background-image]="gradient">Text Here</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not appear to work. The text is just transparent with no gradient appearing. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-beknvy?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: @GriffinMoyer, ::glups:: The before code works in FireFox (I don't check in others navigators). I update the answer. the "key" is change the `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

1. One way is use  `@HostListener`. which is preferred by angular docs.
   [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8qbzc5?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
 gradient: string ='linear-gradient(270deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)';

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(e: any) {
    var angle = this.mouseAngle(e.clientX, e.ClientY);
    this.gradient = `linear-gradient(${angle}deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)`;
  }

  mouseAngle(X: any, Y: any) {
    ...
  }
```

2. Use `Renderer2`. It help us to manipulate the DOM. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wgawas?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
  gradient: string = 'linear-gradient(270deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)';
  mouseFunc: any;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mouseFunc = this.renderer.listen('document', 'mousemove', e => {
    var angle = this.mouseAngle(e.clientX, e.ClientY);
    this.gradient = `linear-gradient(${angle}deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)`;
    });
   }

   mouseAngle(X: any, Y: any) {
    ...
   }
```

3. OR you can use the reactive way `RxJS`, I love this one [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-toufvp?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
  gradient: string = 'linear-gradient(270deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)';
  subscription!: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = 
         fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                           .subscribe((e:any) => {
                            var angle = this.mouseAngle(e.clientX, e.ClientY);
                            this.gradient = `linear-gradient(${angle}deg, #FA8BFF 0%, #2BD2FF 42%, #2BFF88 90%)`;
                           });
  }
  


  mouseAngle(X: any, Y: any) {
    ...
  }
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: These are helpful but not exactly what I was looking for. I am hoping that the text itself has the gradient, not the background of the text. This is why I have `background-clip` set to `text`. I will update the question to be more clear.